# w3c link checker says "400": malformed URL that cannot be parsed by the server

Tags: hyperlink, w3c, malformed

I have a small website and am just about to update and fix mistakes in order to get clean code. I checked with w3c link checker and it says on 50% of my pages:

code 400: malformed URL that cannot be parsed by the server.
As it is, the links work fine and are also found on search engines.
I tried to put examples here without code (I could not figure out how to format code to be seen correctly), but this is beyond me...

```
<a href="../falzmaschinen_produktion.htm">FALZMASCHINEN Docufold</a>
```

(I fear problems with the directory level....)

Comment: What about absolute path rather than relative?

Comment: I dreaded this answer... I use relative paths because I have the same (handmade) navbar with drop down menu on all pages, and said pages are on different directory levels. Is there maybe another solution? At the time I did that, it was said that relative paths also are quicker while loading the page (Ladezeit). Is this not relevant any more?